# single SQL Query to fetch results from tables with Many-Many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table named **IMAGES** in which there is attribute name `img_ID` which is the **primary key**,

there is another table called **Favorites** in which there are two attributes 'img_ID' & `user_ID` ... `img_ID` serves as the **foreign key** to an image and `user_ID` serves as **foreign key** to the user

NOW i need details of from **IMAGES** of all the `img_ID`s from **Favorites** where `user_ID` is some *x-value*

this i could do like this, b.t.w i am using PHP & mySQL

```
$gett = mysql_query("SELECT img_ID FROM favorites WHERE user_ID='".$variable."'");

if( mysql_num_rows($gett) > 0 )
{
  while( $steps = mysql_fetch_assoc($gett) )
  {
     $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE img_ID='".$steps['img_ID']."' ORDER BY img_Date");

         if( mysql_num_rows($res) > 0 )
         {
            while( $result= mysql_fetch_assoc($res) )
            {
               echo $result['img_Name'];
               echo $result['img_Desc'];
               echo $result['img_ext'];
            }
         else 
            echo "no images were found";
  }
}
else 
  echo "no favorites were found";
```

THE PSEUDO CODE will be like

```
RUN QUERY
for each img_ID where user_ID is this
    RUN QUERY    
    for each img_ID
        perform DISPLAY
```

This methodology has a flaw & a back-draw

FLAW       = the order which is on time stamp is destroyed

back-draw = there is a query in nested loop..

**QUESTION:** Can this all be done in with query? if Yes then How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
select
  i.*
from
  favorites f
  join images i on f.img_id = i.img_id
where
  f.user_id = <user id>
```

Also, change your code to use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and prepared statements with bind variables to both improve performance and eliminate the threat of sql injection attacks.

Comment: Your query has some mistakes and I'd suggest PDO over mysqli. Every major PHP ORM is built on it for good reason.

Comment: is that the EXACT Syntax or there is something i need to put instead of i & f

Comment: @Dan Grossman - "some mistakes" = "a one letter typo".  But thanks, fixed it.  And I don't do a lot of PHP, so I'll defer to you on PDO, but either would be better than straight `mysql_query`

Comment: You need to try to understand the query and what it's doing. Blindly copying and pasting others' work does not help you learn to write the next query. I highly recommend the book "Simply SQL" if you'd like to learn. It's full of examples and easy to understand.

Comment: @Junaid Saeed - That's it.  `i` and `f` are table aliases, defined in the `from` clause.  The `as` keyword is optional.

Comment: if aliases then my query could be will be `SELECT imgaes.* FROM favorites JOIN images ON favorites.img_id = images.img_id WHERE favorites.user_id = <user id>' & yes i don't understand whats going on in this query

Comment: whats the difference between join & inner join

Comment: Nothing, the `inner` keyword is optional.

Comment: worked fine.......... now can anyone please give a link or tutorial so that i can learn what happened in the query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.*   -- possibly would need to be "SELECT DISTINCT i.*" instead
FROM images AS i
    INNER JOIN favorites AS f
        ON f.img_ID = i.img_ID
WHERE f.user_ID = ???
```

Comment: DISTINCT has no use because in favorites table the tuple img_ID & user_ID serve as my primary key

Answer (score 0):

No loops, just query both tables.

```
SELECT 
    images.*
FROM
    images
INNER JOIN
    favorites
ON
    favorites.img_ID = images.img_ID
WHERE
    favorites.user_ID = X
```